# Why are 'session' and 'params' available as local variables in the view but not 'errors'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can write:

```
<%= debug(params) %>
<%= debug(session) %>
```

but not:

```
<%= debug(errors) %>
```

Why is the `errors` variable not available locally in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming errors refers to validation errors, `params` and `session` apply to your entire request and are therefore made available to your controller and views. `errors` apply to a specific model that you have instantiated (e.g. a person who is missing a name or a post which is missing a title) so there is no request-wide list of errors.